# Pandas Dataframe - Count values based on index position

Tags: python, pandas

I need to keep track of each position of a named column. So if the first column has the same name k times, its value would be 1*k. It's best shown in an example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name':['n1', 'n2', 'n3']})
df1['pos'] = df1.index + 1

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name':['n1', 'n3', 'n4']})
df2['pos'] = df2.index + 1

print "df1:\n", df1, '\n'
print "df2:\n", df2, '\n'

# Hack
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on='name', how='outer')
df3 = df3.fillna(0)
print df3

# Sum the desired values
df3['pos'] = df3.pos_x + df3.pos_y
del df3['pos_x']
del df3['pos_y']

# Produce desired output
print "\nDesired Output:\n", df3
```

The output is:

```
df1:
  name  pos
0   n1    1
1   n2    2
2   n3    3 

df2:
  name  pos
0   n1    1
1   n3    2
2   n4    3 

  name  pos_x  pos_y
0   n1      1      1
1   n2      2      0
2   n3      3      2
3   n4      0      3

Desired Output:
  name  pos
0   n1    2
1   n2    2
2   n3    5
3   n4    3
```

In `df1` and `df2`, the `pos` column is being constructed by the index. I'm not picky, the `pos` column could be the same as the index.

Anyone know a more compact way to get the counts in the final `pos` column for each of the names?

I need to sum like this over hundreds of thousands of dataframes that I'll calculate iteratively, where `pos` column represents the performance of each `name`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option is to [concat](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.tools.merge.concat.html) rather than merge:

```
In [11]: df4 = pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

Then you can groupby 'name', and sum the result (pos):

```
In [12]: g = df4.groupby('name', as_index=False)

In [13]: g.sum()
Out[13]: 
  name  pos
0   n1    2
1   n2    2
2   n3    5
3   n4    3
```